# ffmpeg flash frames last still image in concat sequence

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor

I want to concat several pictures into a video. Each picture must have its own duration. I use the most recent windows build for ffmpeg (20170204) and the guide from http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow/

Here is my text file:

```
file path/to/001.png
duration 5
file path/to/002.png
duration 6
```

I try using the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i path/to/input.txt output.mp4
```

In the resulting video, the first pictures hangs for 5 seconds but the second picture only hangs for 0 seconds (I only see a glimpse of it). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the demuxer example at Wiki doesn't work. Reproduced by me. Adding a duplicate entry of the last image alters total duration unpredictably.

Comment: No. There is a concat filter which is different from the fps filter. In any case, neither of those are used here. Filters are processors invoked by `-vf`, `-af` or `-filter_complex`. Here, the concat demuxer is used, which is a different process.

Comment: Doesn't work here. Supply a different duration for the duplicated entry and check.

Comment: Bug report [filed](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6128).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussion at the bug tracker, this should be a workaround:

```
file path/to/001.png
duration 5
file path/to/002.png
duration 5.96
file path/to/002.png
```

and

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i path/to/input.txt -vsync vfr output.mp4
```

The idea is to duplicate the entry of the last image. If you need the duration to be precise, then decrease the duration of the now 2nd-last entry by `1/fps` seconds. For 25 fps video, that's 0.04s. If you don't do this, the output duration will be 0.04s longer.

Comment: Make sure to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` for broad player compatibility.